# how can I pass value from textfield to object or file(serializable file)?

Tags: java, swing

ive got the layout codes ready(i have 3 classes).
after i inputed the
first name, last name, address, age and salary then i clicked the button "save", it should save on the Employee.ser file and it should not overwrite every time i save the input information.

```
import javax.swing.*;    
import java.awt.*;    
import java.io.*;    
import java.util.*;    
public class EmployeeApp extends JFrame    
{    
    private ArrayList <Employee> list;    

public EmployeeApp()
{
    list = new ArrayList<Employee>();
}

JPanel panel;
JLabel label;
JTextField field;
JFrame frame;
JButton save;


public void initialize()
{
    panel = new JPanel();
    frame = new JFrame("Mark");
    save = new JButton("save");
    frame.add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, save);
    getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(350,350);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(12,0));

    JLabel label = new JLabel("Enter First Name ");
    field = new JTextField(20);
    frame.add(BorderLayout.CENTER,panel);
    panel.add(label);
    panel.add(field);


    label = new JLabel("Enter Last Name ");
    field = new JTextField(20);
    panel.add(label);
    panel.add(field);

    label = new JLabel("Enter Adress ");
    field = new JTextField(20);
    panel.add(label);
    panel.add(field);

    label = new JLabel("Enter Age ");
    field = new JTextField(20);
    panel.add(label);
    panel.add(field);

    label = new JLabel("Enter Salary ");
    field = new JTextField(20);
    panel.add(label);
    panel.add(field);


}


public void start()
{
    initialize();
}

private void load()
{
    File empFile = new File("Employee.ser");
    if(empFile.exists())
    {
        try
        {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(empFile);
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            Employee emp = null;
            while((emp = (Employee) ois.readObject()) != null)
            {
                list.add(emp);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){}
    }
}    
}
```

---

```
import java.io.*;    

public class Employee implements Serializable    
{    

private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String address;
private int age;
private double salary;




    public void setFirstName(String first) {
            firstName = first;
    }
    public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String last) {
            lastName = last;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
            return lastName;
    }

    public void setAddress(String ad) {
            address = ad;
    }
    public String getAddress() {
            return address;
    }

    public void setAge(int ag){
        age = ag;
    }
    public int getAge(){
        return age;
    }

    public void setSalary(double sal){
        salary = sal;
    }
    public double getSalary(){
        return salary;
    }    
}
```

---

```
     public class EmployeeLauncher    
{    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception    
    {    
        EmployeeApp em = new EmployeeApp();    
        em.start();    
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Add an ActionListener to the save button.
2. Override actionPerformed to handle save action (Get the values from textFields).
3. Load all the object inside the file (What you done in `load()`)
4. Create a `FileOutputSteram` and use `writeObject()` method of `ObjectOutputStream` to write all objects in your list.

Comment: thanks for the tips. x-x
can i get an example on the number 2 tip? ._.
i dont really know how to get the values from textfield. =/

Comment: You have to create different TextField as global, for example, private JTextField nameField; in the EmployeeApp. In the actionPerformed function, get the value by calling getText() of JTextField. That is, String lastName = nameField.getText().

Comment: please check the code and tell me what i did wrong. x-x it still doesnt save on the Employee.ser. :(

Answer (score 0):

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class EmployeeApp extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    private ArrayList     <Employee> list;

public EmployeeApp()
{
    list = new ArrayList<Employee>();
}
Employee obj = new Employee();

JPanel panel;
JLabel label;
JTextField field;
JFrame frame;
JButton save;
private JTextField nameField;

public void initialize()
{
    nameField = new JTextField();
    panel = new JPanel();
    frame = new JFrame("Mark");
    save = new JButton("save");
    frame.add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, save);
    getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(350,350);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(12,0));

    JLabel label = new JLabel("Enter First Name ");
    field = new JTextField(20);
    frame.add(BorderLayout.CENTER,panel);
    panel.add(label);
    panel.add(field);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


    label = new JLabel("Enter Last Name ");
    field = new JTextField(20);
    panel.add(label);
    panel.add(field);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    label = new JLabel("Enter Adress ");
    field = new JTextField(20);
    panel.add(label);
    panel.add(field);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    label = new JLabel("Enter Age ");
    field = new JTextField(20);
    panel.add(label);
    panel.add(field);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    label = new JLabel("Enter Salary ");
    field = new JTextField(20);
    panel.add(label);
    panel.add(field);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    save.addActionListener(this);
    load();




}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    load();
    obj.setFirstName(nameField.getText());
    obj.setLastName(nameField.getText());
    obj.setAge(nameField.getText());
    obj.setAddress(nameField.getText());
    obj.setSalary(nameField.getText());

}


public void start()
{
    initialize();

}

private void load()
{
    File empFile = new File("Employee.ser");
    if(empFile.exists())
    {
        try
        {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(empFile);
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

            Employee emp = null;
            while((emp = (Employee) ois.readObject()) != null)
            {
                list.add(emp);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){}
    }
}
  private void saveObject()
{
    try
    {
        File empFile = new File("Employee.ser");
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(empFile);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        for(Employee emp : list)
        {
            oos.writeObject(emp);
        }
        oos.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e){}
}

}
```

Comment: Call save() at the end of actionPerformed